# Import from excel to sqlite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview

Using c# and sqlite

I want to click on a button, choose an excel spread sheet, .xls or xlsx, save it into the sqlite database and also display on a datagridview next to the button. A lot of the suggestions I see are only for rewriting all the data in the database to save it or saving it through the datagridview.

The problem with this is that I want to save the data from the spreadsheet on top of the existing data inside the database already and the datagridview needs to show all the data in the sqlite.

Any suggestions on how to go about it? I can export but just can't figure a way to import.

Comment: Have you considered a NoSQL Aproach to this?

Comment: **import** you mean importing excel spread sheet (xls / xlsx) to a `datagridview`?

Comment: Nope never considered NoSQL. Could give it a try to understand though.

Comment: Import as in save the data from the excel spread sheet to the sqlite database which can then be viewed through the datagridview. I want the datagridview to show the previous data AND the added data at the bottom if that's possible. Not sure if import is the correct word as some correct me and some don't.

Comment: @timetoquitcoding so you are doing an insert? checking the spreadsheet you prepared and find out which lines are not exist in database then insert them to the database?

Comment: @timetoquitcoding or insert whatever in the spreadsheet to database?

Comment: Insert whatever. The spreadsheet should have the same columns.

Comment: @timetoquitcoding Insert whatever? Read in spreadsheet to datagridview and loop every row and run insert statement will do.

Comment: True. I know how to do the insert part but the reading excel I'm not really confident on it. More or less I would just copy paste the codes I find on it sadly. Thanks anyways for being patient.

Comment: @timetoquitcoding I compile these comments into answer below, if it solve your problem you may mark my answer correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any suggestions on how to go about it? I can export but just can't figure a way to import.

Ideally you should have **UPLOAD** `Button`, **IMPORT** `Button` and a `DataGridView`.

**UPLOAD**

Load your excel spreadsheet by locating it in somewhere else(folders) transform the excel spreadsheet into `DataGridView`.

**IMPORT**

Loop every row in `DataGridView`, and run insert statement to `sqlite` database. After all row has been insert, you may clear your `DataGridView` and read from `sqlite` database again.